# Carousel wouldn't fill div

Tags: css, width, carousel

I'm trying to fill a div with an carousel. I got it to work but the carousel wouldn't fill the width of the entire div and I can't seem to be able to get it to work.

I made a jsfiddle to let you see: 
https://jsfiddle.net/svdvem97/

I'd like to fill the div with just a little bit of padding on the sides, but whatever I try, the width of the carousel wouldn't change.

Thanks in advance.

```css
#wrapper
{
 background: rgba(162,162,162,.1);
}

#banner-wrapper
{
 overflow: hidden;
 padding: 3em 0em;
 background: #E24E2A;
}

#banner
{
 overflow: hidden;
 width: 1000px;
 padding: 0px 100px;
 text-align: center;
 color: rgba(255,255,255,.7);
 border-bottom: 2px solid #E3E3E3;
}

#banner a
{
 color: rgba(255,255,255,.9);
}

#banner .box-left
{
 float: left;
}

#banner .box-right
{
 float: right;
}

#banner h2
{
 margin: 0em;
 padding: 0em;
 font-weight: 400;
 font-size: 1.6em;
 color: #F8F8FF;
}

#banner span
{
 display: block;
 padding-top: 0.20em;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-size: 1.2em;
 color: #A2A2A2;
}

.carousel {
    position:relative;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.64); 
    margin-top: 10px;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.carousel-inner {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
 
}

.carousel-open:checked + .carousel-item {
    position: static;
    opacity: 100;
}

.carousel-item {
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.6s ease-out;
    transition: opacity 0.6s ease-out;
}

.carousel-item img {
    display: block;
    height: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
}

.carousel-control {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.28);
    border-radius: 50%;
    color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: none;
    font-size: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 35px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, -50%);
    cursor: pointer;
    -ms-transform: translate(0, -50%);
    transform: translate(0, -50%);
    text-align: center;
    width: 40px;
    z-index: 10;
}

.carousel-control.prev {
    left: 2%;
}

.carousel-control.next {
    right: 2%;
}

.carousel-control:hover {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    color: #aaaaaa;
}

#carousel-1:checked ~ .control-1,
#carousel-2:checked ~ .control-2,
#carousel-3:checked ~ .control-3 {
    display: block;
}

.carousel-indicators {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 2%;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 10;
}

.carousel-indicators li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 5px;
}

.carousel-bullet {
    color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    font-size: 35px;
}

.carousel-bullet:hover {
    color: #aaaaaa;
}

#carousel-1:checked ~ .control-1 ~ .carousel-indicators li:nth-child(1) .carousel-bullet,
#carousel-2:checked ~ .control-2 ~ .carousel-indicators li:nth-child(2) .carousel-bullet,
#carousel-3:checked ~ .control-3 ~ .carousel-indicators li:nth-child(3) .carousel-bullet {
    color: #428bca;
}

#title {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 27px;
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    z-index: 9999;
    text-shadow: 0px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.33), -1px 0px 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper" class= "container">
 <div id="banner" class="container">
  <div class="carousel">
   <div class="carousel-inner"> 
    <input class="carousel-open" type="radio" id="carousel-1" name="carousel" aria-hidden="true" hidden="" checked="checked">
     <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="https://fakeimg.pl/2000x300/0079D8/fff/?text=Test">
     </div>
    <input class="carousel-open" type="radio" id="carousel-2" name="carousel" aria-hidden="true" hidden="">
     <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="https://fakeimg.pl/2000x300/DC5732/fff/?text=Test">
     </div>
    <input class="carousel-open" type="radio" id="carousel-3" name="carousel" aria-hidden="true" hidden="">
     <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="http://fakeimg.pl/2000x300/289672/fff/?text=Test">
     </div>
    <label for="carousel-3" class="carousel-control prev control-1">‹</label>
    <label for="carousel-2" class="carousel-control next control-1">›</label>
    <label for="carousel-1" class="carousel-control prev control-2">‹</label>
    <label for="carousel-3" class="carousel-control next control-2">›</label>
    <label for="carousel-2" class="carousel-control prev control-3">‹</label>
    <label for="carousel-1" class="carousel-control next control-3">›</label>
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
     <li>
      <label for="carousel-1" class="carousel-bullet">•</label>
     </li>
     <li>
      <label for="carousel-2" class="carousel-bullet">•</label>
     </li>
     <li>
      <label for="carousel-3" class="carousel-bullet">•</label>
     </li>
    </ol>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added style to #banner class

```css
#wrapper
{
 background: rgba(162,162,162,.1);
}

#banner-wrapper
{
 overflow: hidden;
 padding: 3em 0em;
 background: #E24E2A;
}

#banner
{
 overflow: hidden;
  /* set width to 100% */
 width: 98%;
  /* delete the padding */
  /* added margin */
  margin :0 1%;
 text-align: center;
 color: rgba(255,255,255,.7);
 border-bottom: 2px solid #E3E3E3;
}

#banner a
{
 color: rgba(255,255,255,.9);
}

#banner .box-left
{
 float: left;
}

#banner .box-right
{
 float: right;
}

#banner h2
{
 margin: 0em;
 padding: 0em;
 font-weight: 400;
 font-size: 1.6em;
 color: #F8F8FF;
}

#banner span
{
 display: block;
 padding-top: 0.20em;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-size: 1.2em;
 color: #A2A2A2;
}

.carousel {
    position:relative;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.64); 
    margin-top: 10px;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.carousel-inner {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
 
}

.carousel-open:checked + .carousel-item {
    position: static;
    opacity: 100;
}

.carousel-item {
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.6s ease-out;
    transition: opacity 0.6s ease-out;
}

.carousel-item img {
    display: block;
    height: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
}

.carousel-control {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.28);
    border-radius: 50%;
    color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: none;
    font-size: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 35px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, -50%);
    cursor: pointer;
    -ms-transform: translate(0, -50%);
    transform: translate(0, -50%);
    text-align: center;
    width: 40px;
    z-index: 10;
}

.carousel-control.prev {
    left: 2%;
}

.carousel-control.next {
    right: 2%;
}

.carousel-control:hover {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    color: #aaaaaa;
}

#carousel-1:checked ~ .control-1,
#carousel-2:checked ~ .control-2,
#carousel-3:checked ~ .control-3 {
    display: block;
}

.carousel-indicators {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 2%;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 10;
}

.carousel-indicators li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 5px;
}

.carousel-bullet {
    color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    font-size: 35px;
}

.carousel-bullet:hover {
    color: #aaaaaa;
}

#carousel-1:checked ~ .control-1 ~ .carousel-indicators li:nth-child(1) .carousel-bullet,
#carousel-2:checked ~ .control-2 ~ .carousel-indicators li:nth-child(2) .carousel-bullet,
#carousel-3:checked ~ .control-3 ~ .carousel-indicators li:nth-child(3) .carousel-bullet {
    color: #428bca;
}

#title {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 27px;
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    z-index: 9999;
    text-shadow: 0px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.33), -1px 0px 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper" class= "container">
 <div id="banner" class="container">
  <div class="carousel">
   <div class="carousel-inner"> 
    <input class="carousel-open" type="radio" id="carousel-1" name="carousel" aria-hidden="true" hidden="" checked="checked">
     <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="https://fakeimg.pl/2000x300/0079D8/fff/?text=Test">
     </div>
    <input class="carousel-open" type="radio" id="carousel-2" name="carousel" aria-hidden="true" hidden="">
     <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="https://fakeimg.pl/2000x300/DC5732/fff/?text=Test">
     </div>
    <input class="carousel-open" type="radio" id="carousel-3" name="carousel" aria-hidden="true" hidden="">
     <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="http://fakeimg.pl/2000x300/289672/fff/?text=Test">
     </div>
    <label for="carousel-3" class="carousel-control prev control-1">‹</label>
    <label for="carousel-2" class="carousel-control next control-1">›</label>
    <label for="carousel-1" class="carousel-control prev control-2">‹</label>
    <label for="carousel-3" class="carousel-control next control-2">›</label>
    <label for="carousel-2" class="carousel-control prev control-3">‹</label>
    <label for="carousel-1" class="carousel-control next control-3">›</label>
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
     <li>
      <label for="carousel-1" class="carousel-bullet">•</label>
     </li>
     <li>
      <label for="carousel-2" class="carousel-bullet">•</label>
     </li>
     <li>
      <label for="carousel-3" class="carousel-bullet">•</label>
     </li>
    </ol>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: +1! Thanks for the quick reply! I thought it would be something like that, but I didn't thank of exactly that.

Comment: I had to wait several minutes before I could mark it as resolved ;)

Answer (score 0):

1) you defined `padding:0 100px;` this shift `#banner` to right.

2) you use of `width:1000px`,if width browser be less than 1000px,scroll is created,so use width:100% and max-width:1000px;

```
#banner {
    width: 100%;<----------------------Changed
    padding: 0;<-----------------------Changed
    max-width:1000px;<-----------------Changed
    //more code...
}
```

```css
#wrapper {
  background: rgba(162,162,162,.1);
}

#banner-wrapper {
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 3em 0em;
  background: #E24E2A;
}

#banner {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  max-width:1000px;
  padding: 0px;
  text-align: center;
  color: rgba(255,255,255,.7);
  border-bottom: 2px solid #E3E3E3;
}

#banner a {
  color: rgba(255,255,255,.9);
}

#banner .box-left {
  float: left;
}

#banner .box-right {
  float: right;
}

#banner h2 {
  margin: 0em;
  padding: 0em;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 1.6em;
  color: #F8F8FF;
}

#banner span {
  display: block;
  padding-top: 0.20em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  color: #A2A2A2;
}

.carousel {
  position:relative;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.64); 
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.carousel-inner {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  
}

.carousel-open:checked + .carousel-item {
  position: static;
  opacity: 100;
}

.carousel-item {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.6s ease-out;
  transition: opacity 0.6s ease-out;
}

.carousel-item img {
  display: block;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.carousel-control {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.28);
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: none;
  font-size: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 35px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, -50%);
  cursor: pointer;
  -ms-transform: translate(0, -50%);
  transform: translate(0, -50%);
  text-align: center;
  width: 40px;
  z-index: 10;
}

.carousel-control.prev {
  left: 2%;
}

.carousel-control.next {
  right: 2%;
}

.carousel-control:hover {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  color: #aaaaaa;
}

#carousel-1:checked ~ .control-1,
#carousel-2:checked ~ .control-2,
#carousel-3:checked ~ .control-3 {
  display: block;
}

.carousel-indicators {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 2%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 10;
}

.carousel-indicators li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 5px;
}

.carousel-bullet {
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  font-size: 35px;
}

.carousel-bullet:hover {
  color: #aaaaaa;
}

#carousel-1:checked ~ .control-1 ~ .carousel-indicators li:nth-child(1) .carousel-bullet,
#carousel-2:checked ~ .control-2 ~ .carousel-indicators li:nth-child(2) .carousel-bullet,
#carousel-3:checked ~ .control-3 ~ .carousel-indicators li:nth-child(3) .carousel-bullet {
  color: #428bca;
}

#title {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px auto;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 27px;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  z-index: 9999;
  text-shadow: 0px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.33), -1px 0px 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper" class= "container">
  <div id="banner" class="container">
    <div class="carousel">
      <div class="carousel-inner"> 
        <input class="carousel-open" type="radio" id="carousel-1" name="carousel" aria-hidden="true" hidden="" checked="checked">
          <div class="carousel-item">
            <img src="https://fakeimg.pl/2000x300/0079D8/fff/?text=Test">
          </div>
        <input class="carousel-open" type="radio" id="carousel-2" name="carousel" aria-hidden="true" hidden="">
          <div class="carousel-item">
            <img src="https://fakeimg.pl/2000x300/DC5732/fff/?text=Test">
          </div>
        <input class="carousel-open" type="radio" id="carousel-3" name="carousel" aria-hidden="true" hidden="">
          <div class="carousel-item">
            <img src="http://fakeimg.pl/2000x300/289672/fff/?text=Test">
          </div>
        <label for="carousel-3" class="carousel-control prev control-1">‹</label>
        <label for="carousel-2" class="carousel-control next control-1">›</label>
        <label for="carousel-1" class="carousel-control prev control-2">‹</label>
        <label for="carousel-3" class="carousel-control next control-2">›</label>
        <label for="carousel-2" class="carousel-control prev control-3">‹</label>
        <label for="carousel-1" class="carousel-control next control-3">›</label>
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
          <li>
            <label for="carousel-1" class="carousel-bullet">•</label>
          </li>
          <li>
            <label for="carousel-2" class="carousel-bullet">•</label>
          </li>
          <li>
            <label for="carousel-3" class="carousel-bullet">•</label>
          </li>
        </ol>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```